# VB 6 Multi-threading confusion

Tags: c++, multithreading, vb6

My question is about the multi-threading in VB 6. This seems to be an out-of-date question since fewer people are using VB 6 now.

Definitely, the native VB 6 doesn't support multi-threading directly. So I make a C++ dll then and expose a method which calls CreateThread to create a worker thread and some other methods to control the thread. The thread seems to be fine.

To notify back to the VB 6 application, I firstly pass Me.hWnd to the dll and hook the WndProc before creating the thread. Then, call SendMessage to the hWnd where needs. It is also seems to be Ok.

Is this method stable for using multi-threading in VB 6? I really need your help!

PS: How about [SHCreateThread](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=31786&lngWId=1) API instead of CreateThread?

Comment: You have to call `SendMessage` on the thread the `hWnd` is created on. What you're doing will go up in smoke the minute you put it in production. (FYI, VB6 supports threading through ActiveX EXEs.)

Comment: @wqw SendMessage (I change it to PostMessage to prevent potential blocks) is called on C++ thread rather than the 'UI' (or Main) thread. I suppose the message be send across threads. Why do you think it will not work?

Comment: For an overview (with links to further reading) of how VB6 handles threading, see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261361(v=vs.60).aspx).  "In-process component" is an ActiveX DLL.  "Out-of-process component" is an ActiveX EXE.

Comment: @BobRodes Emm. they both have limitations. I am about to use my .dll approach because I think "If I call windows system APIs, some of them may create new threads in it. VB 6 is able to call these kinds of APIs means that creating thread in .dll is safe" and "Windows Message approach is nothing with COM contract (so, it is safe) and it is certainly thread-safe approach."

Comment: @guanboshen Each window is associated with an owner thread it is created on. You can call `SendMessage` only on the owner thread, which is a documented limitation of win32 message queues. But yes, you *can* `PostMessage` cross threads which is good enough for notifications. Passing data is the problem (params/retval). You can rely on COM to do the marshaling, or use threading primitives and thread-sync data exchange manually.

Comment: @wqw Passing data is handled by wParam and lParam of the message. Using wParam to pass the length of the data and lParam to pass the data pointer allocated in .dll (on heap). The data (heap) is freed in VB 6.0 after being used.

Comment: Yes, this kind of custom marshaling should do the trick. It's not very performant (kind of like using heap alloc/free on each and every method call) and not very convenient (no equivalent of output params, so worker thread cannot receive cancellation request for instance) but should be stable enough unless posted messages are missed by VB6 thread and heap leaks start accumulating.

Comment: @wqw Yes, you give me a important information: I at least have to free allocated heap in .dll if PostMessage fails. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your .dll approach, but there is actually a bit of a trick you can use within VB6 to create additional threads, sort of.  If you drop a timer object on your form, set it to fire in, say, 1 ms, the timerevent that fires will be in a separate thread.  From there you can call whatever other functions you need.  I used this trick frequently back in the day for background processing and whatnot.

Pro Tip:  *deactivate the timer immediately* once it fires or mayhem will ensue.

Comment: It is able to start the thread in this way, but not able to control it afterwards.

Comment: @guanboshen No thread is started using VB6 timer controls, ever.